# How can I prove that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-1/2|}} \, dx < \infty.$ in Lebesgue measure?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

How can I prove that   $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-1/2|}} \, dx < \infty.$ in Lebesgue measure?

**My thought:**

Using the Monotone Convergence theorem, but still I am stuck in applying it, could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x}}\,\mathrm d x\quad \text{and}\quad \int_{1/2}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{2}}}\,\mathrm d x$$
are convergent improper integrals of positives functions. So, obviously $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\frac{1}{2}-x|}}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1)$.

Comment: You should be able to compute them ;-) What is the derivative of $\sqrt{x-1/2}$ of $\sqrt{1/2-x}$ ?

Comment: No, with Lebesgue integral, you integrate on open sets.

Comment: To be more precise, the set $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are null sets, so integrating with or without them is the same.

Comment: but we do not calculate lebesgue integrals using derivatives.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I wanted to use the theorem that if the function is bounded and remann integrable on a closed interval then it is Lebesgue integrable.... or what theorem is you referring to ?

Comment: @Mathstupid I am referring to $\int_{[0,1]} = \int_{(0,1)}$.

Comment: if an function is Riemann integrable, then its Lebesgue integral is computed in the same way.